# Vuzix Speech SDK language support

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, vuzix

I want to program an Android App for my Vuzix m300 smart glasses. Using the Vuzix Speech Recognition SDK I want the App to recognize number words in german. In the official docu is mentioned that one should have the correct language recognition files loaded. Where can I find these files and how can I load them?

here is the link to the documentation:
https://vuzix-website.s3.amazonaws.com/files/Content/Upload/sdk-speechrecognitionservice-javadoc-1.5_v2.zip

The files are mentioned at 'insertPrase'

Comment: Please mention the things that you have tried and what error/issues you have faced instead of just posting a question and link. That will give more closure and ability to answer clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in the same issue I think,

You first need to change the Language of the Vuzix (in Settings/Language), in theory the right speech recognition language will be loaded.
You can see in the log the actual localized voice commands by doing a

```
sc = VuzixSpeechClient(this.activity)
sc.dump()
```

In practice:
- you may need to reboot the glass just after changing the language to force a refresh
- we have no info on the speech recognition performance and expected pronunciation, so it is a lot of trials/errors

Comment: I have had good luck here recently. The speech engine automatically loads the required files when the system language changes. The only constraint as a developer is to change the system language, then test that language.  It does not work to insert German phrases while the system is in English.